# Invalidate select when the first option is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I am going to validate select box (ngOption) by first value (if first value is selected - false, if not - true) and I do not want to use predefined value within select box like this:

```
<select id="mainVideo" class="form-control"
      ng-model="qtTestData.mainVideo"
      ng-options="mainVideo for mainVideo in mainVideoSources"
      name="mainVideo"
      required>
   <option value="">-- Please, select a value --</option>
</select>
```

So, I have such select box:

```
<select id="mainVideo" class="form-control" requiredSelect
      ng-model="qtTestData.mainVideo"
      ng-options="mainVideo for mainVideo in mainVideoSources"
      name="mainVideo"
      required>
</select>
```

My array is:

```
 $scope.mainVideoSources = ['Please, select a value', 'Value1', 'Value2'];
```

I am using this directive to define if first value selected (it means that user did not change the value)

```
App.directive('requiredSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            attributes.requiredSelect = true; 

            var validator = function(value) {
                if ( value != 'Please, select a value' ) { 
                    ngModel.$setValidity('requiredSelect', false);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ngModel.$setValidity('requiredSelect', true);
                    return true;
                }
            };
            ngModel.$formatters.push(validator);
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validator);
            attributes.$observe('requiredSelect', function() {
                validator(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML that should appear if invalid value selected:

```
<div class="has-error bg-danger" ng-show="qtTestForm.mainVideo.$error.requiredSelect">
   <p class="text-center">Oops, something wasn't right</p>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work...
And How can statement `(value != 'Please, select a value')` be rewritten in Angular way? In JS 
it's something like this select.selectedIndex == 0

Answer (score 1):

You could just separate your data into "data values" and "display values":

```
sources = [{
    value: '',
    label: 'Please select a value'
}, {
    value: 'value1'
}, ...]
```

and then use

```
<select ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in sources" required ...></select>
```

to make the `required` validator do the rest. No need to create your own directive.

---

*As a sidenote, if you are creating a validation directive, use `ngModelController.$validators` (not `$parsers` & `$formatters`). Also, you don't need to check for `ngModel` presence, if you have it as mandatory requirement.*

Comment: thank you, but I am getting the array from the server, so I have to find a way, how to validate on the first value into the select

Comment: Getting the data from the server doesn't prevent you from transforming it to suit your needs. `[{ value: '', label: 'Please select a value' }].concat(data.map(function (value) { return { value: value }; }))` Or, if you really want to only adjust the template, create your `<option>`s manually using `ng-repeat` and `ng-value`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array of values, use array of objects, like this:

```
$scope.mainVideoSources = [ { "value": 0, "text": "Please, select a value" }, {{ "value": 0, "text": "Value1"}, { "value": 0, "text": "Value2"} ];
```

Answer (score 0):

@hon2a,
Native Angular validation works good, thanks. I have rewritten my directive on $validators. Now it looks

```
App.directive('requiredSelect', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.requiredSelect = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;
            var requiredSelect = 'Please, select a value'; //TBD.. select first ngOption
            return value != requiredSelect;
        };
    }
};
```

});

and it works for me.